# POST request from Retrofit works in unexpected way

Tags: http, https, retrofit2, okhttp

There is a third-party website that uses HTTPS and where the start page performs a POST upon login. I have inspected that POST request in my browser and then I have been able to manually create the request with Fiddler's composer. Thus, depending on the credentials, I could either successfully or unsuccessfully log in with Fiddler. The return code is always 302, which comes along with either a redirect (header "Location") to the user management page or a login failed page, respectively.

However, when I create that request using the Retrofit library, it does not work. I get response code 200, which in this specific case is not to be considered a success.

In order to inspect the POST request from Retrospect, I have directed it to Fiddler (http://localhost:8888) instead of the third-party URL. If I copy that request into the composer and adjust the URL to be the third-party one, the request does work. I.e., I could not find anything wrong with the request built by Retrofit.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

My code is written in Kotlin, but should be easily understandable if you know Java:

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.*

interface MyApi {
    @POST("<relative login url>")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers(
        //...
    )
    fun login(
        @Field("username") username: String, 
        @Field("password") password: String
    ) : Call<ResponseBody>;
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val baseUrl = "https://<url>"
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).build()
    val myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
    val code = myApi.login("<username>", "<password>").execute().code()
    println(code)
}
```

Comment: I guess you're using retrofit with ``OkHttp`` which in by default has ``followRedirects`` set to true, thus you never get a 302 because the redirect is followed by default. An easy way to check this is to initialise retrofit with a custom ``OkHttpClient`` by setting the ``followRedirect`` properties to false. There's 2 if I'm not mistaken, one also for Https requests if I remember correctly. Try it out and let us know.

Comment: Works like a charm! You may post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, but to make it more understandable to others too here goes an answer.

When using `retrofit` with `okhttp` redirects will be followed by default. The reason for this is because the default `okhttp` client is set to follow redirects. This is why you never get a `302` - The redirect is followed automatically and you get the `200` from the followed url.

You can disable this behaviour by building your retrofit instance with a properly configured okhttp client:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false)
            .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            // other configurations for retrofit
            .build();
```

Notice that here we create an instance of retrofit with a client configure **not** to follow redirects. This will effectively make you receive the `302` and other redirect codes.

*(note that I didn't fully configure the retrofit instance here to focus the answer in the important part)*